# Ext JS 4 Neptune theme number field issue

Tags: css, extjs4

While using the Neptune Theme the icons beside the number field are placed at top right of the form panel. All the icons are having a CSS LEFT and TOP properties - however, for the numberfield icon, it takes the position relative to the From Panel. Other icons are placed at its right position. Check the image attached and the css class:

[image]

```
.x-form-trigger::after 
{
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 6px;
width: 11px;
height: 11px;
content: "";
background: url('../../resources/themes/images/neptune/triggerfield.png') no-repeat;
}
```

I want to place the icons at its correct position. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `position: relative` to `.x-form-spinner-up` and `.x-form-spinner-down`. Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/QfZQX/3/